# How do I call the 巾 radical?

Tags: readings, radicals

Every source I look it says it's called はば AND きん. But in what situation do I call it きん instead of はば?

Also, it's usually specified as はばへん and きんへん, in my understanding へん radicals are always on the left of the kanji. So how do I call 巾 in kanjis such as 市, 常, and  姉?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But in what situation do I call it きん instead of はば?

To refer to the 巾 radical - never.

<sup>There are [rare cases](https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%AE%8F#.E7.B5.83.28.E7.B3.B8.29) in which 巾 is pronounced this way as a noun. And of course 巾 is pronounced キン in many compound words.</sup>

> 幅

はばへん or less often きんべん

> 市

はば

Comment: Thank you very much. I was hoping someone could answer the second part of the question but it seems that that's not gonna happen. I'm having a hard time figuring out how people refer to radicals in japanese, so that's another step =)

Comment: @FelipeMüller I don't understand what you mean by "second part". I answered all questions you asked in the original post.

Comment: Oh, the question was how do you call 巾 in kanjis like: 市, 常, and 姉? Do you call them はばへん even though the radical is not on the left part of the kanji?

Comment: And I answered that.